# How works adding tags on github profile?

Tags: github

Sorry by the ask, but I would like to know how works adding tags on github profile. Can I adding tags of subjects that I have interesting on my github profile, or I need of a plan different of Free Plan? Or what I seems most logical to me: is only possible adding tags across deploying of projects.

Who could indicate a website that covers how to use the features of github intended for beginners, please do it. I antecipate my thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github profiles have no tags. Language tags are selected based on the language of your *existing* contributions. You *can*, however, [create a tag in Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging), within a certain project.

A tag is basically a reference to a single commit and its contextual history behind it. Use `git tag -a name -m 'message'` and when you run `git tag` it'll show up i the list.